# Teradata bteq console not transribing in powershell transcipt

Tags: powershell, teradata

I run a pwhs.exe with transcript teradata bteq like below

I used to have the bteq console output in transcript, but when run **via windows task scheduler**, the bteq output does not show anymore.

If I run ps1. when loggonon to server, the transcripts shows all.

pwsh: version 7.0.3
server: windows 2016 os
terdata: 16.2

```
    start-transcript -path C:\temp\test.txt -append 

    $psfunctions = 'C:\ps_funtions' 
    .Psfunctions 

   #in functions function
   #function func-bteq ($b_file) { 
   #                             get-content $b_file -raw | bteq  
   #                            }

    write-host 'Start' 
    
    func-bteq -b_file $b_file     
   
    write-host "End, with  $LASTEXITCODE"

    foreach ($f in get-childitem 'C:\modules\'-inculde *.sql -recurse) 
    {
     write-host 'Start something'
     write-host $.name 
     $b_file = get-content $f -raw   
     func-bteq -b_file $b_file
     write-host $LASTEXITCODE 
    }
  stop-transcript
```

In transcript file I ony get ps console like

```
Transcript started, output file is E:\20200928041908.txt
SQL start 041909
file_a.sql
SQL ready 041959
file_b.sql
SQL start 041959
file_c.sql
**********************
PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20200928042340
**********************
```

Where I expect something like

```
SQL start 041909
file_a.sql

+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Version 1.0. created 11-05-2019 WvW                                            */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.logon db/user,

 *** Logon successfully completed.
 *** Teradata Database Release is 16.10.06.04
 *** Teradata Database Version is 16.10.06.04
 *** Transaction Semantics are BTET.
 *** Session Character Set Name is 'ASCII'.

 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.

+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* delete and insert in to save table                                             */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
delete table all;

 *** Delete completed. 267527 rows removed.
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.


+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
insert into table_a
select * from table_b

 *** Insert completed. 267523 rows added.
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.LOGOFF;
 *** You are now logged off from the DBC.
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
.EXIT 0;
 *** Exiting BTEQ...
 *** RC (return code) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself,  in powershell core 7.x

Add | out-host to the line, than the BTEQ console output will be in also powershell transcript